# localstorage not returning text on reload

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time using localstorage in an html page where have an input element where I can insert text . When I reload my page I wnat the text to stay there but it doesn't .

```js
//function to store name on localstorage
function storeName(){
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  localStorage.setItem("user" , name.value);
  name.value= localStorage.getItem("user");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="storeName()" id="name" placeholder="Enter name"/>
```

Comment: Does `storeName` run on reload? If not, `name.value` will not be set.

Comment: `name.value` is not set on reload, so you override the stored "user" in the local storage with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes are set correctly on `localStorage`.
When reloading, you can not see the text because you have not loaded the value.

Load the localStorage value on page load.

```js
function storeName(){
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  localStorage.setItem("user" , name.value);
}

document.getElementById("name").value= localStorage.getItem("user");
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="storeName()" id="name" placeholder="Enter name"/>
```

Comment: Where have you tested? @vasilis123

Comment: If working well on your side, could you pls approve my answer?

Comment: Yes I can in 3minutes